# error reading db in joomla

Tags: joomla

While i run a component i am getting **500 - An error has occurred error reading db** in joomla.

My configuration file is perfect.

I don't know what else to change..

Any guidance will be helpful

Thanks in advance...

```
//No direct acesss
defined('_JEXEC') or die();

jimport('joomla.application.component.model');

class DealsModelDeals extends JModel {

function getDeals(){
    $db = $this->getDBO();

    $db->setQuery('SELECT * from #__todaysdeal');
    $deals = $db->loadObjectList();

    if ($deals === null)
    JError::raiseError(500, 'Error reading db');

    return $deals;
}

function getDeal($id){
    $query = ' SELECT * FROM #__todaysdeal '. ' WHERE id = '.$id;
    $db = $this->getDBO();
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $deal = $db->loadObject();

    if ($deal === null)
    JError::raiseError(500, 'Deal with ID: '.$id.' not found.');
    else
    return $deal;
}


/**
         * Method that returns an empty greeting with id 0
         *
         * @access    public        
*/

function getNewDeal(){
    $dealTableRow =& $this->getTable('deals');

    $dealTableRow->id=0;
    $dealTableRow->clientName='';
    return $dealTableRow;
}

/**
         * Method to store a greeting in the DB
         *
         * @access    public        
*/

function saveDeal($deal)
{

    //Parameter not necessary because our model is named DealsModelDeals (used to ilustrate that you can specify an alternative name to the JTable extending class)
    $dealTableRow =& $this->getTable('deals');

    //print_r($dealTableRow);
    //print_r($_FILES); exit;
    // Bind the form fields to the todaysdeal table
    if (!$dealTableRow->bind($deal)) {
        JError::raiseError(500, 'Error binding data');
    }

    // Make sure the deal record is valid
    if (!$dealTableRow->check()) {
        JError::raiseError(500, 'Invalid data');
    }

    // Insert/update this record in the db
    if (!$dealTableRow->store()) {
        $errorMessage = $dealTableRow->getError();
        JError::raiseError(500, 'Error binding data: '.$errorMessage);
    }

    $id = $dealTableRow->id;

    if(!empty($_FILES['dealImage']))
    {

        $file = $_FILES['dealImage'];
        $id = $dealTableRow->id;

        if ((($_FILES["dealImage"]["type"] == "image/gif") || ($_FILES["dealImage"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") || ($_FILES["dealImage"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")) && ($_FILES["dealImage"]["size"] < 150000))
        {
            if ($_FILES["dealImage"]["error"] > 0)
            {
                echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["dealImage"]["error"] . "<br />";
            }
            else
            {
                if (file_exists("components/com_deals/dealImages/" . $_FILES["dealImage"]["name"])) {
                     $_FILES["dealImage"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
                } else {
                    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["dealImage"]["tmp_name"], "components/com_deals/dealImages/" .$id."_".$_FILES["dealImage"]["name"]);
                    echo "Stored in: " . "dealImages/" . $_FILES["dealImage"]["name"];
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }

     $dealImage = $_FILES['dealImage']['name'];
     $dealImage .= (!empty($_FILES['dealImage']['name'])) ? ' ' . $_FILES['dealImage']['name'] : '';
     $query = "UPDATE #__todaysdeal SET dealImage='".$id."_".$_FILES['dealImage']['name']."' WHERE id='".$id."'";

    $db = $this->getDBO();
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $db->query();
    //If we get here and with no raiseErrors, then everythign went well
}

function deleteDeals($arrayIDs)
{
    $query = "DELETE FROM #__todaysdeal WHERE id IN (".implode(',', $arrayIDs).")";
    $db = $this->getDBO();
    $db->setQuery($query);
    if (!$db->query()){
        $errorMessage = $this->getDBO()->getErrorMsg();
        JError::raiseError(500, 'Error deleting Deals: '.$errorMessage);
    }
}

function dealsUploadPhoto($file, $id)
{
    //UPLOAD FILE

            $config = & JComponentHelper::getParams('com_deals');   
            $allowed = array('image/pjpeg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/png', 'image/x-png', 'image/gif', 'image/ico', 'image/x-icon');
            $pwidth  = $config->get('pwidth');
            $pheight = $config->get('pheight');
            $maxsize = $config->get('maxsize');

            if($file['size'] > 0 &&  ($file['size'] / 1024  < $maxsize)){           

            if(!file_exists(JPATH_SITE . DS. 'images' . DS . 'deals'))
            {
                if(mkdir(JPATH_SITE . DS . 'images' . DS . 'deals')) {
                    JPath::setPermissions(JPATH_SITE . DS . 'images' . DS . 'deals', '0777');
                    if(file_exists(JPATH_SITE . DS . 'images' . DS . 'index.html')) {

                        copy(JPATH_SITE . DS . 'images' . DS . 'index.html', JPATH_SITE . DS . 'images' . DS . 'deals/index.html');
                    }
                  }
            }

                if($file['error'] != 0){
                    tpJobsMsgAlert('Upload file photo error.');
                    exit ();
                }

                if($file['size'] == 0){
                    $file = null;
                }

                if(!in_array($file['type'], $allowed)) {
                    $file = null;
                }

                if ($file != null){
                    $dest = JPATH_SITE.DS.'images'.DS.'deals'.DS.$id.'.jpg';

                    if(file_exists($dest))
                    {
                        $del = unlink($dest);
                    }

                    $soure = $file['tmp_name'];
                    jimport('joomla.filesystem.file');
                    $uploaded = JFile::upload($soure,$dest);

                    $fileAtr = getimagesize($dest);
                    $widthOri = $fileAtr[0];
                    $heightOri = $fileAtr[1];
                    $type = $fileAtr['mime'];
                  $img = false;
                  switch ($type)
                  {
                    case 'image/jpeg':
                    case 'image/jpg':
                    case 'image/pjpeg':
                      $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($dest);                     
                      break;
                    case 'image/ico':
                      $img = imagecreatefromico($dest);
                      break;
                    case 'image/x-png':
                    case 'image/png':
                      $img = imagecreatefrompng($dest);
                      break;
                    case 'image/gif':
                      $img = imagecreatefromgif($dest);
                      break;
                  }

                  if(!$img)
                  {
                    return false;
                  }

                  $curr = @getimagesize($dest);

                  $perc_w = $pwidth / $widthOri;
                  $perc_h = $pheight / $heightOri;
                  if(($widthOri<$pwidth) && ($heightOri<$height))
                  {
                    return;
                  }

                  if($perc_h > $perc_w)
                  {
                    $pwidth = $pwidth;
                    $pheight = round($heightOri * $perc_w);
                  }
                  else 
                  {
                    $pheight = $pheight;
                    $pwidth = round($widthOri * $perc_h);
                  }


                  $nwimg = imagecreatetruecolor($pwidth, $pheight);
                  imagecopyresampled($nwimg, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $pwidth, $pheight, $widthOri, $heightOri);

                  imagejpeg($nwimg, $dest, 100);
                  imagedestroy($nwimg);
                  imagedestroy($img);
                }   

            }else{
                if($file['size'] / 1024  > $maxsize){
                    dealsMsgAlert('Size of file photo is too big. Maximum size".$maxsize." KB');
                    exit ();
                }

            }
}

function dealsMsgAlert($msg)
{
    if (!headers_sent())
    {
        while(@ob_end_clean());
        ob_start();
        echo "<script> alert('".$msg."'); window.history.go(-1); </script>\n";
        $out = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        echo $out;
        exit();
    }
    echo "<script> alert('".$msg."'); window.history.go(-1); </script>\n";      
    exit(); 
}
```

}
?>

Comment: which component is that?

Comment: my own component.. just to save data to db. i am newbie to components.

Comment: does the site itself work? is problem only with your component? Are you connection to non-native db?

Comment: site is working well.. problem is with my component

Comment: kind of hard to analyze without knowing much... This is not common error message. are you using MVC? for database are you using `$db =& JFactory::getDBO();` or creating your own instance? Can you give some more info...

Comment: Please would you post your model code (if you are using MVC) that is relevant to your database read, and insert.

Comment: I am using MVC pattern and i am using this for database...$db =& JFactory::getDBO();

Comment: http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=2156660. This is the sample code what i used for my task

Comment: That cannot be your code as there is no 500 error with the text "An error has occurred error reading db" contained within. Your question is poorly asked and your lack of providing your code even though we've asked a number of times leaves to spend my time on other people's problems.

Comment: sorry martin... My code are in folder structure and there are many files. i am confused to show what page i want to.. that's y i show you the model.. sorry regarding it. Please view now..

Comment: do your tables in database have proper prefix? You are using `#__todaysdeal` in db (by default) should be `jos_todaysdeals`.

Comment: You should look for the code "JError::raiseError(500, 'An error has occurred error reading db');" as you say the error written contains "An error has occurred error reading db". Therefore somewhere in your code it raising this error. I can't see this code in your model so maybe this is in your controller or somewhere else. You can try to grep your code for "An error has occurred error reading db" to find in which file it is located.

Comment: @@Alex: Yes i have done the proper prefix.. I don't think that will be an error because it doesn't even read the DB. Excuse me if anything wrong

Answer (score 0):

The problem that causes the red screen with 500 Error is happening because you are raising an exception if the requested quote is does not exist. You should not use `JError::raiseError()`.

Use one of the following instead:

```
// This will set error to the model. You can get the errors from
// the model by your controller $model->getErrors() and output them to the screen.
$this->setError('ERROR MESSAGE GOES HERE');
```

OR

```
// This will output errors to the screen right the way
JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage('ERROR MESSAGE GOES HERE', 'message');
```

---

Model already has `_db` property, you do not need to get db into variable. You can access it like this `$this->_db`. You can read about [Joomla Model class here](http://api.joomla.org/Joomla-Framework/Application/JModel.html).

Also within your model you are using

```
$db = $this->getDBO();
$db->setQuery('SELECT * from #__todaysdeal');
$deals = $db->loadObjectList();
```

Model has simplified method to load list of object, like so

```
$deals =& $this->_getList('SELECT * from #__todaysdeal');
```

Comment: The problem is most likely not that the error is getting raised, but rather what is causing the error to be raised...

Comment: well that is true. He can see what queries are executed if he does not get `500 Error`, this is just a step to help resolve the problem. My guess is that his tables dont have corresponding names, left out prefix or he just does not have data in `#__todaysdeal` and `getDeals()` causes ERROR because of that.